# What are the next steps for unit testing with dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

I'll start out by saying I'm a huge fan of unit testing. I've been using it for a couple of years. So far, though, my use has been limited to ensuring engineering calculations are performed correctly, strings are formatted properly, etc. Basically, testing my work on class libraries to be consumed in other projects.

Now, I want to branch out and apply unit testing to my work on ASP.NET Web API. At this point I have my controller written and working with Ninject. Although I'm using Ninject, I'm still not 100% sure why I'm doing it and haven't seen the benefits yet.

On to my question, what are the next steps for unit testing my Web API controllers? What should I do next and when will I reap the benefit of using Ninject?

Answer (score 2):

Next, you could create fake data (or a mock) that your controller can return to your views.  This will allow you to do front end development without having to complete the back end implementation.

The benefit of using Ninject is that you can create mock objects for testing purposes.  By injecting the interface instead of the concrete implementation you can easily switch between the real and mock object.  To do this you simply change which one should be injected in the Ninject bindings.  Using something like Rhino Mock in conjunction with Ninject you can write and test your code (controllers, views, etc) without having to fully implement all of the functionality.  When you're ready to implement a mocked piece of functionality, you don't have to rewrite your code to accommodate the changes, you simply update your bindings.  Now real data will display on your pages instead of the mocked data you created previously.

Comment: Agreed. Ninject (and DI) makes it trivially easy to swap out implementations on the fly. This can be handy during initial development, and can also be handy as your requirements change to require a different class implementation, or if you want to re-use some components but wire up different back-end implementations for a new project.